# Child view controller's viewDidLayout invokes before parent's viewDidLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I'm trying to make a view controller which works like `.popover` modal presentation style view controller. Because a tooltip in child view controller should layout based on parent's `sourceView` or `sourceItem`, the child view controller has reference to parent's specific `UIView` or `UIBarButtonItem`.

(Because I draw most content in the tool tip, I can't use auto layout.)

I configure child view controller's layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and it worked fine, but issue occurs when device orientation changes.

When device orientation is changed, `child.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called before `parent.viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, and it makes child view controller's configure its layout based on the parent view controller's old layout which is before orientation changes.

It seems the only way to figure out is to call `child.view.setNeedsLayout` from `parent.viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, but I want to leave it as a plan B.

Is there a natural way to handle this?

**ADDED**

I just made a sample project to make sure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let vc = ModalViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print(#file)
    }
}
```

```
class ModalViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print(#file)
    }
}
```

The log was as below:

```
// when loaded
TestProject/ViewController.swift
TestProject/ModalViewController.swift

// when rotated
TestProject/ModalViewController.swift
TestProject/ViewController.swift
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong here. `layoutSubviews` is propagated from the top down. If that’s not what you’re seeing, perhaps your overrides are somehow subverting the normal mechanisms. Make sure you are calling `super` in all relevant overrides and that you are not forcing premature layout.

Comment: That is why I'm asking. It seems something weird happening with `overCurrentContext` modal. I added a sample code I tested with.

Comment: Does `top down` mean from top most view to bottom most view?

Comment: I forgot that. What I needed was to call `presentedViewController?.view.setNeedsLayout` from parent, so it will call modal's `viewDidLayoutSubview()`.

Comment: Ok so your original question didn’t mention `overCurrentContext` modal. Maybe that’s what makes the difference. Or I could just be wrong!